# Error: Pass content as json or plain text

Tags: laravel

I am using guzzle to post data to the api as below. When i post, the api returns `Error: Pass content as  json or plain text`. Is it possible to convert content to JSON or Plain Text in the code below

How can I resolve this?

**Controller**

```
 $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ];

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'headers' => $headers
        ]);

        $body = '{
            "item" : Summer-Jacket,
            "content" : Hi
         }';
       
        $url = "https://api.com";
        $request = $client->post($url, 
        [
            'body' => $body
        ] );
        $response = $request->send();
```

Comment: Please check there is "json" key available to pass JSON data in API request. Like you have done headers data.

Comment: Did my question help you or do you still have problems?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your body is not even valid JSON. Strings needs to have `"string"` around them

To post JSON with guzzle, you can instead use the `RequestOptions` for exactly that.

```
$result = $client->post("https://api.com", [
    RequestOptions::JSON => [
        'item' => 'Summer-Jacket',
        'content' => 'hi',
    ]
)->getBody();
```